# Android studio databinding error, Cannot find symbol: debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/databinding/ActivitySignupBinding.java

Tags: android, data-binding, androidx, 2-way-object-databinding, cannot-find-symbol

project/build.gradle

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.0'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.4.0'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.0'
    calligraphyVersion = '2.2.0'
    glideVersion = '3.7.0'
    roomDatabase = '1.0.0-alpha3'
    rx2FastAndroidNetworking = '1.0.0'

    dagger2Version = '2.11'
    rxjava2Version = '2.0.6'
    rxandroidVersion = '2.0.1'
    placeholderviewVersion = '0.6.1'
    debugDBVersion = '1.0.0'
    timberVersion = '4.5.1'
    lifecycle = '1.0.0-alpha3'

    retrofitVersion='2.3.0'
    GsonVersion='2.7'
    okhttpVersion= '3.8.0'
    googleplus= '11.0.4'
    glideversion= '4.1.1'
    braintree='3.+'
    //Test dependencies
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    mockitoVersion = '2.7.1'
}
```

app/build.gradle

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    signingConfigs {
        ReleaseConfig {
            keyAlias 'test'
            keyPassword 'test'
            storeFile file('../KeyStore/test.jks')
            storePassword 'test'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bz.pie.rider"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.ReleaseConfig
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "PEITaxi_User_v$versionName")
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    dataBinding.enabled = true
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':countrylist')
//    implementation project(':slideDateTimePicker')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // dependency injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.7'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.googleplus"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideversion"
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation "com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:$rootProject.braintree"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Robolectric environment
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    // Required for instrumented tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle.properties

```html
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# Android X: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

wrapper.properties

```html
#Mon Nov 18 11:40:24 IST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

i tried changed the version of GRadle and updating the project i ended up with this error
the below image shows the package not found
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRtR5.png)
but the Signup Package is available
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jepnX.png)

request Assistance thanks in advance (caught in this issue realy hard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason (the databinding algorithm is programmed to detect names starting with uppercase as class names and correspondingly names the binding object with them), package names starting with capital letters cause errors with databinding.

I also had a similar issue that cost me several hours of debugging.

I eventually figured out you just need to change the package names to start with a SMALL (LOWER CASE) LETTER AND NOT CAPITAL (UPPER CASE).

Refactor package Splash to splash, Signup to signup, and do the same for other packages starting with a capital letter,  clean then rebuild your project. If still doesn't work, invalidate android studio caches and restart your computer

Comment: thanks it worked the project compiles and runs But now i get this error
[ClassNotFoundException: config_inputEventCompatProcessorOverrideClassName androidx, running on andoridx crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965782/classnotfoundexception-config-inputeventcompatprocessoroverrideclassname-androi)

Comment: I would try to see if I can debug the new error you are getting. But meanwhile, you can kindly give my answer the green checkmark as the answer to your issue and upvote if possible.

Comment: sure and it was much helpful,

Comment: yes it worked thanks and my other questions was also solved with your help thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59129135/9191757

Answer (score 0):

it's not about data binding, sometimes when doing a bad field initializing in model it happened.

go to messages of logcat and watch there.

before it clean and rebuild project

update me in comments

it's a common problem in realm models but you don't use it and i will help you solve this issue.

Comment: thanks @alireza daryani  i get the same erro
'error: cannot find symbol class Signup'
this error is inside Databinding class
could you help me with the code i could share you please